# Active Directory Security - User Group vs User privileges

Tags: security, permissions, active-directory, privileges

I have denied to a specific user to write on a file. 
But this user is a member of a User Group which can write on this file. 
So there is a conflict between User vs. User-Group rights.
Which one will prevail here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any "deny" should rule trump any "allow" rule, regardless of whether the deny or the allow was assigned to a user or a group.  For a brief discussion, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/06/08/3150719.aspx.  For more details, see the "Access Control Lists" and "Access Control Entries" sections at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374862.aspx.